# How can I programmatically determine the creator of a Domino database?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'm using the built-in Domain Catalog database to list all the databases on a particular Domino server. I'm creating a custom view to show certain information about each database. What I'd like to have is a column that displays the creator of each database. However, if the Domain Catalog is keeping track of this information, I can't find it.

Is there a field in the Domain Catalog that provides this information that I just haven't been able to find? Is there some other way I might find this information and get it into this view? @DBlookup and related functions don't work in column formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That information is not stored in the catalog, and is probably not stored in the database either (It's not shown on any of the property tabs).

You would probably need to get/write a server add-in to monitor database creation and store that data somewhere. Then you'd need to account for databases created by adminp/replication - your add-in might pick them up as having been created by a server.

This question was also asked in the [R4/R5 forums in 1998](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/46dom.nsf/55c38d716d632d9b8525689b005ba1c0/bed18751bdad2d248525660a00716c2a?OpenDocument) and received no answer.

Comment: A worthy attempt at a solution, but I am only interested in the creators of existing databases, in an effort to track down who is responsible for each of the many databases on our very poorly maintained Domino server. My next step is to try to glean something meaningful from the Managers list.

Comment: Not an enviable task. Your only other option would be to restore the servers log.nsf and parse it for DB creation events. This is impractical and time consuming.

Comment: It's immaterial who created the database. They may be long gone. It's that current list of managers you should use. You might also use the user history of the application to see who's been accessing it recently, but it's possible that would only record replication activity, so you might need to follow up by looking up the replicas on the other servers it's replicated with.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. There is no such attribute for database, but you can dig for some clues.

New databases: use NotesNoteCollection and look for some specific design element (icon, for example) and look for first element in $UpdatedBy field.

New copies/from templates: above mentioned method won't work. It will return info from original/template, not current database. In this case, try using Created property of DB and check user footprints after that date - in ACL log (he probably altered ACL immediately after copy), new design elements (probably made new view, folder, agent...) or profile documents.

Answer (score 0):

What Frantisek said.  Looking in the log archive (ugh!) may tell you who deployed it, but in a well run environment that won't be who developed it.  A list of $UpdatedBy(0) for all design notes should give you a good idea.  The catch will be that it mayl be people who left the company years ago. : )